# CSS Slide Div outside of container

Tags: javascript, html, css, angular, css-animations

I have a (flex) container with two divs (**DIV 1**, **DIV 2**) that are next to each other.

In the default state **DIV1** and **DIV 2** are visible.

- **DIV 2** has a fixed width (e.g. 40% of the container width).
- **DIV 1** uses width that is not occupied by **DIV 2**.

I would like to implement a sliding window that lets **DIV 2** further slide in from the right with a transition/animation.

**DIV 1** slides out of the container to the left during transition until it is temporarily not visible (but still present in DOM).

Currently, I tested several ways to increase the width of DIV 2.

However, it never worked to run a smooth transition/animation. Does anyone know how to implement this?

HTML:

```
    <div class="container">
    <div id="left">Left side div</div>
    <div id="right">Right side div </div>
    </div>
```

CSS:

```
    .container {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    height: 200px;
    width: 400px;
    border: 2px solid;
    gap: 10px;
    overflow: hidden;
    cursor: pointer;
    }
 
   #left {
   flex: 1;
   background-color: red;
   transition: 0.5s;
   }
 
   #right {
   width: 40%;
   background-color: blue;
   }
 
  .container:hover > #left {
  transform: translate(-100%);
  }
```

[image]

Comment: may be this link can help you :
[Animating an element to go left, outside of div](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71932309/animating-an-element-to-go-left-outside-of-div)

Comment: Hi may be this link can help you
[Animating an element to go left, outside of div](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71932309/animating-an-element-to-go-left-outside-of-div)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  height: 200px;
  width: 400px;
  border: 2px solid;
  gap: 10px;
  overflow: hidden;
  cursor: pointer;
}

#left {
  flex: auto;
  background-color: red;
  transition: .5s linear;
}

#right {
  flex: 0 0 40%;
  background-color: blue;
  transition: .5s linear;
}

.container:hover>#left {
  margin-left: -100%;
}

.container:hover>#right {
  flex: 0 0 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div id="left">Left side div</div>
  <div id="right">Right side div </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Where does the gap on the left side come from? Can you adjust your code so that the blue div really takes up 100%? I was not able to get rid of it, even when I removed the 10xp gap, which would actually be important to keep.

Comment: I changed animation property and used margin-left instead of transform. does it help you?

Comment: That's what I wanted to implement. I got it & was able to adapt it successfully. Thanks!